# ¿Cual es el código ASCII del la rueda del mouse?

Tags: vb.net, scroll, ascii

quiero saber cual es el código `ascii` de la rueda del mouse para implementarla en un `GetAsyncKeyState` y de esa forma desplazar el `scroll` de un `TrackBar` sin que este tenga el foco o la ventana que lo contenga este activa.

Comment: prueba con este : GETMOUSE x,y(,wheel,(buttons))  fuente :http://ascii-world.wikidot.com/mouse-manipulation-technique

Comment: el evento wheel creo que esta deprecado

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel



End Sub
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).